# discord.py ошибка в коде

Tags: python, discord.py

написал код:

````
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "word" or "apple" or "juice" in message.content:
          await message.channel.send("Something")
    await client.process_commands(message)```
````

после запуска данного кода, бот начинает бесконечно спамить в чат слово "Something"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это выражение всегда `True`:

```
if "word" or "apple" or "juice" in message.content:
```

Если логически разделить его, то будет:

```
if ("word") or ("apple") or ("juice" in message.content):
```

А т.к. `if "word"` всегда `True`, то проверять дальше нет смысла

**Правильно будет так:**

```
if "word" in message.content or "apple" in message.content or "juice" in message.content:
```

---

**UPD.**

Кст, если слов много, то список слов можно проверить через функцию `any`:

```
if any(word in message.content for word in ["word", "apple", "juice"]):
```